# Searching in Lucene .Net

Tags: lucene.net, stemming

I have used Lucene .Net for Indexing and using StandardAnalyzer to at time of Indexing. Now I want to search say 'attach'. In document 'attached' is there. How i get the successful hit for word 'attach'. Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Ashish, did you find the right answer somewhere else? If so, please add it as an answer below. If my answer was the correct one, please accept it by clicking the big check mark next to it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Reducing word forms to their roots is called "[stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)" in search engine software.  Look at the first answer to [How to enable stemming when searching using lucene.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192671/how-to-enable-stemming-when-searching-using-lucene-net) for a few options for stemmers using Lucene.net.