# lucene and plurals

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

If you look at the [comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438000/how-do-i-implement-tag-searching-with-lucene) you'll see

> Lucene is very much the tool to do
>   this. If you want apple and apples
>   (plural) to match, you just need to be
>   careful about using the correct
>   language stemmer when indexing and
>   querying the index.

I'm new to lucene and barely understand how adding and saving document work.

How do I search my tag field so apples and apple are the same?

I am using [lucene.net 2.9.1](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/tags/Lucene.Net_2_9_1/src/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for the stemming algorithm here is an [example reduced for plurals](http://www.mail-archive.com/java-user@lucene.apache.org/msg00399.html)

You may find [how-to-enable-stemming-when-searching-using-lucene-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192671/how-to-enable-stemming-when-searching-using-lucene-net) helpful for .net